# error in arm-neon asm linking with C++ in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android native assembly,I'm trying to link the arm-neon asm function with c++. but its not linking.I have followed the following website given below. If using the function in that website its compiling and calling the armfunction ,while i try with my code its showing error undefined reference to myfunction.
      If same function i wrote in c and asm the compiler compiling and if any error exist in asm code its shows the error.

http://www.eggwall.com/2011/09/android-arm-assembly-calling-assembly.html

regards
VS

Comment: What does the relevant parts of your code look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply,
our code look like

```
    .text
.global fastForwardDst
.type   fastForwardDst, %function
```

fastForwardDst:

@Doing operation
@

```
.size   fastForwardDst, .-fastForwardDst
```

and saved as "forward.s" and we added in Android.mk.